# How to fix this prog which using ocamlyacc?

Tags: compiler-construction, ocaml, ocamlyacc

parser.mly:

```
%{
  let env=Hashtbl.create 10
%}
%token  INT
%token SUB
%token EOL
%token EQUAL
%token NAME
%left SUB

%start main             /* the entry point */
%type  main
%%
 main:
  statement_list EOL                { $1 }

statement_list:
  {}
  |statement statement_list {}

statement:
 assign_statement{}
 |print_statement{}

assign_statement:
 var EQUAL expr {Hashtbl.add env $1 $3}

print_statement:
 var {print_int(Hashtbl.find env $1)}

expr:
   INT                     { $1} 
  | expr SUB expr           { $1 - $3}
  
var:NAME {$1}
```

lexer.mll:

```
{
open Parser
exception Eof
}
rule token = parse
  [' ' '\t']     { token lexbuf }     (* skip blanks *)
| ['\n' ]        { EOL }
 | ['0'-'9']+ as lxm { INT(int_of_string lxm) } 
| '-'            { SUB }
|['a'-'z']+ as name {NAME(name)}
|'=' {EQUAL}
| eof            { raise Eof }
```

calc.ml:

```
open Syntax

let _ =
  try
    let a=open_in "test" in
    let lexbuf = Lexing.from_channel a in
    while true do
        Parser.main Lexer.token lexbuf; 
    done
        with Lexer.Eof ->
        exit 0;
```

build.sh:

```
ocamllex lexer.mll
menhir parser.mly
ocamlc -c parser.mli
ocamlc -c lexer.ml
ocamlc -c parser.ml
ocamlc -c calc.ml
ocamlc -o calc lexer.cmo parser.cmo calc.cmo
```

it can work sometimes,it test is:

```
a=1
```

there is no error

it test is:

```
a=1
1=a
```

got:

```
Fatal error: exception Parser.MenhirBasics.Error
```

so the prog can parse more than 1 lines

if test is

```
a=1
a
```

the prog will no print 1

if test is

```
a=1
b
```

the prog will no report a error(b not defined)

the prog is first written useing stdio,it works fine.but I want use it not using stdio.It seems I am not understand ocamlyacc very well.

so how to fix it?Thanks!

Comment: If the behavior is different when using stdin I suspect some terminal processing is different. If you're using a Windows system, one difference might be the handling of end-of-line. Your lexer doesn't have a case for handling carriage return ('\r`). That might make a difference. Also it is important to flush the output as octachron says. I've spent many an hour puzzling over missing  output that was simply delayed  by buffering, not missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work once the trivial typos are fixed, but you may want to update your printing code to:

```
print_statement:
 var {Printf.printf "%d\n%!" (Hashtbl.find env $1)}
```

in order to avoid any buffer flushing issues.